# ASP.NET can't access SQL server in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I  had to reinstall SQL server, and now my app is not able to connect to the new (localhost) installation.  My connection string is using windows   authentication

I'm getting an error message that the login failed for MACHINE\USERX, however that user has full permissions for the SQL Server.  I'm running Windows 10, and if I recall correctly you used to have to add ASPNETUSER, but that user does not exist, nor can I figure out how to have the IDE run as NetworkService etc.

ETA: SQL Server 2014 Express

Comment: Which edition and version of SQL Server are you using? (eg SQL Server Express 2014?)

Comment: What is IIRC? The title says you can't access SQL Server in VS2012. What kind of app is it -- ASP.NET MVC, WPF?